# Wrap a long content in one line | Table

Tags: tables

I create a table with 5 columns, 5th column conation such a description (which is a long long text in each row).

```
\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
\hline
column1                  & column2 & column3 & column4 & column5                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             \\ \hline
knowlesi              & -ve            & +ve                   & +ve                    & A primate malaria parasite commonly found in Southeast Asia.                                                                                                                                                                                            \\
facto                 & -ve            & +ve                   & +ve                    & Rare syndromic condition with (Fibular Aplasia, Tibial Campomelia and Oligosyndactyly with Talar Aplasia).                                                                                                                                              \\
leucoencephalopathy   & -ve            & +ve                   & +ve                    & Brain disorder that predominantly affects the cerebral white matter.                                                                                                                                                                                    \\
fistula-in-ano        & -ve            & +ve                   & +ve                    & Chronic abnormal communication between the epithelialised surface of the anal canal and (usually) the perianal skin.                                                                                                                                    \\
Desmoid               & -ve            & +ve                   & +ve                    & An abnormal growth that arises from connective tissue, which is the tissue that provides strength and flexibility to structures such as bones, ligaments, and muscles.                                                                                  \\
metapneumovirus       & -ve            & +ve                   &                        & Is a recently described respiratory virus.                                                                                                                                                                                                              \\
Tracheobronchomalacia & -ve            & +ve                   &                        & TBM is a condition characterized by flaccidity of the tracheal support cartilage which leads to tracheal collapse. This condition can also affect the bronchi.                                                                                          \\
RESLES                & -ve            & +ve                   &                        & Refer to reversible splenial lesion syndrome.                                                                                                                                                                                                           \\
mal-absorption        & -ve            & +ve                   &                        & Refers to a number of disorders in which the small intestine can't absorb enough of certain nutrients and fluids.                                                                                                                                       \\
acroparesthesias      & -ve            & +ve                   &                        & A condition of burning, tingling, or pricking sensations or numbness in the extremities present on awaking and of unknown cause or produced by compression of nerves during sleep.                                                                      \\
limb-shaking          & -ve            & +ve                   &                        & A rare presentation of transient ischemic attacks.                                                                                                                                                                                                      \\
pineocytomas          & -ve            & +ve                   &                        & A tumor of the pineal gland, a small organ in the brain that makes melatonin (a sleep-regulating hormone).                                                                                                                                              \\
hypomineralisation    & -ve            & +ve                   &                        & A type of enamel defect affecting, as the name suggests, the first molars and incisors in the permanent dentition.                                                                                                                                      \\
neurognathostomiasis  & -ve            & +ve                   &                        & A neglected parasitosis of the central nervous system.                                                                                                                                                                                                  \\
Metastasis            & -ve            & +ve                   &                        & A metastatic cancer, or metastatic tumor, is one which has spread from the primary site of origin (where it started) into different area(s) of the body.                                                                                                \\
myelomatosis          & -ve            & +ve                   &                        & Also called Kahler disease, A type of cancer that begins in plasma cells (white blood cells that produce antibodies).                                                                                                                                   \\
AMRF                  & -ve            & +ve                   &                        & Action myoclonus-renal failure syndrome which is a distinctive form of progressive myoclonus epilepsy associated with renal dysfunction.                                                                                                                \\
arthralgia            & -ve            & +ve                   &                        & Pain in a joint.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        \\
leukopenia            & -ve            & +ve                   &                        & One of the white blood cell disorders.                                                                                                                                                                                                                  \\
fibrodentinoma        & -ve            & +ve                   &                        & Ameloblastic fibrodentinoma (AFD) is a debatable neoplasm with respect to its clinical, biological and histopathological diagnosis.                                                                                                                     \\
infantile-ataxia      & -ve            & +ve                   &                        & Infantile-onset spinocerebellar ataxia (IOSCA), is a severe, progressive neurodegenerative disorder characterized by normal development until age one year, followed by onset of ataxia, muscle hypotonia, loss of deep-tendon reflexes, and athetosis. \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

But it appears like this:

[image]

How can I fix it so the content of the 5th column wrapped in multiline rather than one long line

Any help, please?

Comment: welcome to tex.se! please extend your code to complete, but small document. for reformatting your table is important to know your page layout (so we need to know document class you use and relevant packages loaded in preamble of the your documment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, welcome to tex.se. Second, please next time consider composing a Minimal Working Example (MWE) code showing your document setup that people here can re-run and reproduce your problem. That said, from the available information in your question, it seems that a `tabularx` is suitable for your needs. Also, using `\toprule`, `\midrule`, and `\bottomrule` from the `booktabs` package can make the output much nicer and more readable.

Moreover, if you don't use a float environment around the tabularx (`\begin{table} .. \end{table}`), you should add `\noindent\begin{tabularx} ..` as suggested by @Bernard in a comment. In case of Beamer (I suspect you use it here) you needn't do this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{cX}
\toprule
Manual analysis result & Another heading \\ \midrule
+ve & I want it to be as one long line as multiple lines, so the whole table appears. Any help, please? \\
+ve & I want it to be as one long line as multiple lines, so the whole table appears. Any help, please? \\
\dots & \dots \\
\dots & \dots \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

**Update:**

With the updated information for the question, the table turns out to be large enough that it should be typeset in a sideways mode. Here is a possible solution using the `rotating` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs,rotating}
\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}lcccX@{}}
\toprule
column1               & column2        & column3               & column4                & column5                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 \\ \midrule
knowlesi              & -ve            & +ve                   & +ve                    & A primate malaria parasite commonly found in Southeast Asia.                                                                                                                                                                                            \\
facto                 & -ve            & +ve                   & +ve                    & Rare syndromic condition with (Fibular Aplasia, Tibial Campomelia and Oligosyndactyly with Talar Aplasia).                                                                                                                                              \\
leucoencephalopathy   & -ve            & +ve                   & +ve                    & Brain disorder that predominantly affects the cerebral white matter.                                                                                                                                                                                    \\
fistula-in-ano        & -ve            & +ve                   & +ve                    & Chronic abnormal communication between the epithelialised surface of the anal canal and (usually) the perianal skin.                                                                                                                                    \\
Desmoid               & -ve            & +ve                   & +ve                    & An abnormal growth that arises from connective tissue, which is the tissue that provides strength and flexibility to structures such as bones, ligaments, and muscles.                                                                                  \\
metapneumovirus       & -ve            & +ve                   &                        & Is a recently described respiratory virus.                                                                                                                                                                                                              \\
Tracheobronchomalacia & -ve            & +ve                   &                        & TBM is a condition characterized by flaccidity of the tracheal support cartilage which leads to tracheal collapse. This condition can also affect the bronchi.                                                                                          \\
RESLES                & -ve            & +ve                   &                        & Refer to reversible splenial lesion syndrome.                                                                                                                                                                                                           \\
mal-absorption        & -ve            & +ve                   &                        & Refers to a number of disorders in which the small intestine can't absorb enough of certain nutrients and fluids.                                                                                                                                       \\
acroparesthesias      & -ve            & +ve                   &                        & A condition of burning, tingling, or pricking sensations or numbness in the extremities present on awaking and of unknown cause or produced by compression of nerves during sleep.                                                                      \\
limb-shaking          & -ve            & +ve                   &                        & A rare presentation of transient ischemic attacks.                                                                                                                                                                                                      \\
pineocytomas          & -ve            & +ve                   &                        & A tumor of the pineal gland, a small organ in the brain that makes melatonin (a sleep-regulating hormone).                                                                                                                                              \\
hypomineralisation    & -ve            & +ve                   &                        & A type of enamel defect affecting, as the name suggests, the first molars and incisors in the permanent dentition.                                                                                                                                      \\
neurognathostomiasis  & -ve            & +ve                   &                        & A neglected parasitosis of the central nervous system.                                                                                                                                                                                                  \\
Metastasis            & -ve            & +ve                   &                        & A metastatic cancer, or metastatic tumor, is one which has spread from the primary site of origin (where it started) into different area(s) of the body.                                                                                                \\
myelomatosis          & -ve            & +ve                   &                        & Also called Kahler disease, A type of cancer that begins in plasma cells (white blood cells that produce antibodies).                                                                                                                                   \\
AMRF                  & -ve            & +ve                   &                        & Action myoclonus-renal failure syndrome which is a distinctive form of progressive myoclonus epilepsy associated with renal dysfunction.                                                                                                                \\
arthralgia            & -ve            & +ve                   &                        & Pain in a joint.                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        \\
leukopenia            & -ve            & +ve                   &                        & One of the white blood cell disorders.                                                                                                                                                                                                                  \\
fibrodentinoma        & -ve            & +ve                   &                        & Ameloblastic fibrodentinoma (AFD) is a debatable neoplasm with respect to its clinical, biological and histopathological diagnosis.                                                                                                                     \\
infantile-ataxia      & -ve            & +ve                   &                        & Infantile-onset spinocerebellar ataxia (IOSCA), is a severe, progressive neurodegenerative disorder characterized by normal development until age one year, followed by onset of ataxia, muscle hypotonia, loss of deep-tendon reflexes, and athetosis. \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: `\noindent` before `\begin{tabularx}` would be useful.

Comment: Sure, but the OP didn't add any information about how the tabular is being used (inside a float or not or what documentclass, etc ...), anyway, I'll edit my answer, thank you.

Comment: That's work with me, but when I try to add another column, the problem back to me. Is there something general whatever number of columns I have? @AboAmmar

Comment: @SaraWasl -- That's why I asked you to add a MWE code to get a full answer. Please try to add your code and update your exact requirements; how many columns you need?, how each column should be?, etc. A picture here is not worth a thousand words!

Comment: Well, I update my question right now @AboAmmar

Comment: Good, see my update please.

Comment: Very nice and clear :) Thank you so much @AboAmmar

Comment: You're welcome, it's my pleasure that I could help.